# Consume a docker container inside Django docker container? Connecting two docker containers

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, deep-learning

I have a Django container and I want to consume another DL container inside it? For example, I have a Django app that predicting images classes and I want to make the prediction using a docker container and not a python library. That Django app will be containerised as well. In production, I will have three docker containers: Django container + Postgres container + YoloV5 container. How can I link the Django with the YoloV5 so that the prediction inside the Django will be done using the YoloV5?

I want to connect a deep learning container with Django container to make prediction using the DL container and not a python package.

Comment: What do you mean by "consume" here?  It's very straightforward to make network calls between two long-running containers.  It's fairly difficult (and there are major security concerns) to launch a temporary container from a longer-running one.  For applications like this, a Python wheel will be a much better distribution method than a Docker image.

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I want to do is: to use YoloV5 docker container to make a prediction inside a Django container? I don't want to import the DL model inside the Django container. But rather to connect the two containers together.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to make a network call to the other container. You may find it simplest to wrap the YoloV5 code in a very thin web layer, e.g. using Flask, to create an API. Then call that in your Django container when you need it using `requests`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Nick and others, the solution is: by calling the YoloV5 docker container inside Django container using host.docker.internal. I mean that inside Django container (views.py) I used host.docker.internal to call the YoloV5 container.
Update on 29th March 2023:
Instead of using the host.docker.internal. As suggested by Nick we can use Requests:
An example, say you have two containers A and B "Make sure that both of them are connected together". Container A has a function to add two numbers and I want to use this function in Container B. Then Inside Container B:

```
import requests
data = {
    'x': 5,
    'y': 3
}
response = requests.post('http://containerA:8000/add', json=data)
result = response.json()
print(result) # outputs {'result': 8}
```

Note that ContainerA is running on port 8000.

Comment: Using `host.docker.internal` will route network traffic to the host, which may not be necessary or desired. Your question is tagged `docker-compose`, and if you're using Compose to manage these three services then the easiest solution is to send network requests to the name of the service. E.g. `postgresql://postgres` which Compose will route to the appropriate container on the Compose-created network.  More in [the compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to make a network call to the other container. You may find it simplest to wrap the YoloV5 code in a very thin web layer, e.g. using Flask, to create an API. Then call that in your Django container when you need it using `requests`.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by calling the YoloV5 docker container inside Django container using host.docker.internal. I mean that inside Django container (views.py) I used host.docker.internal to call the YoloV5 container

Comment: Glad you succeeded using a network call as suggested. When an answer resolves your issue, you accept it to mark the question as having a resolution.